Coriolis deviation of a projectile fired north from the equator
I'm hoping someone can explain to me where I'm getting confused.
I wish to calculate the horizontal (eastward) deflection of a projectile fired due north from the equator, due to the Coriolis effect.
I know that a projectile on this trajectory will deflect eastwards as it's latitude decreases, and wish to calculate exactly how much it will deflect, though I'm getting confused reading (seemingly) conflicting answers from people, such as this line from the wikipedia entry on the Coriolis force:

If the velocity is parallel to the rotation axis, the Coriolis force is zero. For example, on Earth, this situation occurs for a body at the equator moving north or south relative to the Earth's surface.

Additionally, any online calculator I tried to use (including the only one I could find which allowed you to specify a direction of travel) returns a value of 0N for the Coriolis force at 0°.
Is there an equation I can use which will allow me to specify a point on the equator, initial velocity, mass, and direction, and will return the eastward deflection?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

About the conditions where no rotation effect will occur.
I first need to implement a simplification.
To give the context of that simplification: there is the classroom demonstration device called air track .
A well known demonstration is: the glider has a contraption that can shoot something like a marble 20 centimeters or so straight upward. Upward launch at an angle very close to 90 degrees. The glider is set in motion, then the marble is launched. The marble is then seen to land right back onto the same spot of the glider that it was launched from. As we know, the explanation is that the horizontal velocity component of the marble is the same as that of the glider, and the upward launch doesn't change the horizontal velocity component.
The simplification: instead of using a ballistic projectile, that is launched at some elevation angle, first consider the case of an object that slides frictionless over a surface, much as the air track glider glides over the track with almost no friction.
Before considering the Earth, first consider a simpler case: frictionless motion over the surface of a rotating cilinder, the axis of rotation is the axis of that cilinder.
We give that cilinder latitude lines and longitude lines.
At some longitude line (we can make that zero longitude), set up for launch. Launch the sliding object along the direction of the longitude line.
The subsequent motion of the object over the surface of the cilinder will be along a helix.
After being launched the object will still have the same angular velocity around the cilinder axis of rotation as it had before the launch, when the object had the same angular velocity as the cilinder. As a consequence, the sliding object will remain on the same longitude line. That is, the motion of the object along a helix will not deviate from the longitude line.

Now to the more complicated case of motion over the surface of a perfect sphere.
Let the launch be from the Equator, in northward direction, with evaluation of the position after a distance of 100 kilometer.
Because of the size of the Earth: for a distance of 100 kilometer the object will deviate negligably from the longitude line. At that scale the motion is negligably different from the case of motion over the surface of a cilinder.
The east-west component of the rotation effect correlates with radial displacement. If you start at the Equator, and you move due north, then your distance to the axis of rotation hardly changes at all, so there will be hardly any rotation effect.



General recommendation: if you want to achieve a hard task, then first handle a simplified version, and only after solving the simpler version add demands, working your way to the harder case.
So I recommend that you start with the case of a sphere, with an object sliding frictionless over the surface of that sphere
Initial state:
An object is co-rotating with the sphere along the Equator.
The velocity of co-rotating with the Earth (at the Equator) is about 1500 km/h. For simplicity take the case of launching the object at that velocity in northward direction. The resultant velocity of the two velocities is a velocity vector at an angle of 45 degrees with the Equator.
The motion of the object is frictionless therefore the motion relative to the inertial coordinate system will be at a constant velocity, and it will remain in the same plane. About that plane: that plane is at a 45 degrees angle with the equator, and the center of the sphere lies in that plane. The motion of the object will be along the intersection of the sphere and the plane. In other words: the motion of the object over the surface of the sphere will be along a great circle that is at a 45 degrees angle with the Equator.
So that great circle has a 45 degrees angle with the Equator, and it has a fixed orientation with respect to the inertial coordinate system. The Earth is rotating underneath that great circle.
The object has a uniform velocity so you know where it will be after, say, 6 hourse of travel. After 6 hours the Earth will have turned 90 degrees of its daily rotation, and from that you can calculate where the object will be relative to the Earth.

Another scenario is to launch in such a way that the combination of launch direction and launch velocity cancels the initial velocity of co-rotating with the Earth, so that after launch the resultant velocity is one that is perpendicular to the Equator. equator.

Ballistic trajectory
If you want an actual ballistic trajectory for the object: that makes things quite complicated.

For an object moving along a ballistic trajectory: in order to travel a very long distance the object must be launched at a significant angle to the local horizontal. The object will then gain a lot of altitude. Since gravity is an inverse square law: at higher altitude gravity is weaker. That must be taken into account.
While it is technically possible to formulate an equation that incorporates all of the above factors it would be totally impractical, so nobody is ever going to do that.
Nowadays, if somebody needs something like that they will use numerical integration to crank the numbers.
(I assume that in the military all forms of artillery use are computer aided. I assume that sort of military software is not publicly available.)


I first addressed the thing that you indicated was confusing to you.
Stackexchange recommends that a post should present a single question: that gives that post focus. The 'single question' recommendation relates to the fact that stackexchange is not a threaded forum. The comment section is for comments, not for conversation. The purpose of that policy is, again, to stimulate focus.

I appreciate your time but I dont feel like this answers my question.
I understand that 100km is a negligible deviation, as it's less than one degree of lattitude.
Suppose I am at 0°N 0°E, and fire due north, such that the projectile's path intersects the surface of the Earth at x°N 0°E.
How do I calculate the lateral drift for all values x between 0° and 90° ?

I think you have to better define how the projectile moves, either physically (ballistic trajectory (pointed up? down?), with/without air drag) or non-physically (stays at same height, not affected by air drag etc).  Note that the term "coriolis force" does not have an agreed-on definition as far as I know.  I am in the camp that says it is not a "force" but a kinematic correction for changing radius due to a non-inertial reference frame.

@MarianoG Indeed the the term "coriolis force" does not have an agreed-on definition. (Further complication: many people are unaware that there are multiple mutually inconsistent views in circulation.) I have created an educational resource with comprehensive discussion. Recommended starting point: Coriolis effect The exposition there connects to the way that meteorologists take the Earth's rotation into account
